# Injector in nutch does not work

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch, hortonworks-sandbox

I try to launch injector in nutch 2.2.1 in Hadoop(hdp sandbox 2.3) with elasticsearch 1.1.1 hbase 1.1.2 gora 0.3  jdk 7 ,but i get this exception :

```
InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:221)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:251)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:273)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:282)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:127)
at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
... 9 more
```